# Reuters news feed conflicts with use of jQuery's '$'

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys having an issue with the reuters news feed. It is preventing my jquery from working. From what I have found googling it seems there is a library conflict or loading issue. The error the console gives is as follws :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function
```

From googling it seems if you change the `$` to `jquery` things are fine but is there another solution for this? Loading the news feed script after? I don't really want to do a sitewide change.

I have setup a jiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Jjj6g/23/

If you remove the `div` with `id=annoying` you will see the `test div` growing and shrinking but not when the reuters feed is put in.

I know this is a bit off the wall but any advice/help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your code within an anonymous function and evaluate it right away. That way you can overwrite a variable only within this function.

Example:

```
    (function($) { 
        $('.something')...; 
    }(jquery));
```

Comment: HI thanks for the answer david, how do I go about wrapping the script inside it. Would I do a doc ready and insert the <script src...> as .html() into the div? Apologies for my naivety.

Comment: My idea was to let the reuters script as it is. Next you add jQuery to your page with the function name 'jquery' instead of '$' to avoid conflicts, then when you write your code, you wrap it in the function statement, as above. => I did it in your jsfiddle.

Comment: I have jquery running all over the site and this would go in sitewide so it is not really an option for me. If I must I will just change all $'s to 'jquery' but I am running php so going to have to be careful. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: Since the Reuters script seems to redefine $ you need to create different scopes for the scripts. Since you include a script from their server you are not able to wrap a function around it to scope it. This leaves the alternative to do so with your own code. -- You could also dig in their documentation to see if theres a possibility to configure their script not to use the $ variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is very common mistake. Usually it means not conflict but just you forgot to add some library. Please check carefully, if all the used libraries included and what is important too, could be found by browser:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Kate, the site's jquery has been running fine throughout development, it is solely when I add the Reuters news feed script that there is an issue, so I don't believe it is a library include issue.

Comment: Sometimes for some reasons library are not loaded at all. The references exist, everything looks good, but libraries has not been loaded. I would suggest you to check "Net" tab of firebug to exclude it as a possible reason.